# Elastic search is not returning last 30mins data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I need to get last 30 mins data from elastic search index. I am reading this query from logstash input plugin. I have used now-30m. but it is not giving correct results. Please help to identify what I am missing here
Query :

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "createdDate": {
              "gte": "now-30m"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Output data has below time which is not in 30 mins range

```
 "createdDate": "2021-11-26T09:10:38.524Z",
 "createdDate": "2021-11-26T06:44:58.520Z",
```

field details in Index.

```
"createdDate": {
"type": "date"
},
```

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about 1) your timezone, 2) the timezone in which Logstash is installed, 3) the timezone in which ES is running? Because `now` is computed dynamically and that also depends on where ES is running.

Comment: 1. My timezone is IST. 2)Logstash script is running in CST timezone 3)ES is running in GMT. I understood the problem now.  how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping and data both look correct.

However, your different systems, Logstash and Elasticsearch, are probably not installed in the same timezone as the one you're calculating from.

Since `now` is computed dynamically, it can be different from what you expect. Make sure to account for the timezone differences.